# Location control is working just one time

Tags: android, location, controls, virtual, device

Manual Location control on Android virtual device is working just one or two times - after that it doesn't respond. I am changing Latitude and Longitude and it doesn't do anything, but button and that TextViews are active. I was working with that a long time and it was always working fine.
It does the same thing on system 'Google Maps' application. 
In my app I have:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Log.w("TAG", "Location was changed"); ...
```

but it write just once (or max. twice).

On real device my app is working fine. 
Restart app, virtual device, eclipse or whole ADB and also PC didn't work.
Thank you for any answer.

Comment: you mean in real device it is working ?

Comment: yes, it was working without any problems. Also this app I'm trying to run it was in the same virtual device working a few days ago...

Comment: i think u r using map v1.it is depricated.use version2 og google maps.

Comment: the same app with the same virtual device was working... and I need work on Android 1.5...